# windows 7 hard drive crashed; Loaded Ubuntu from USB, can't find files that were on win 7 desktop

Tags: hard-drive, hidden-files

I have hard drive that crashed and was running windows 7.  I have a new drive, but need to get vital data off of old drive.  I was successful in making a usb start up with ubuntu.  It loads up and the drive is mounted under devices.  The problem is that the files I need to get off the drive were stored on the windows desktop and when I select the desktop folder, it is empty.  I can see all the other software and programs that were stored on the drive, but not these files.

Any help (in super simple terms, please) is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Karl

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a permission issue? Did you try listing the contents of your desktop folder via "sudo ls " in the terminal?

Comment: I did it pulls up Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public Templates Videos not sure what to do next.